# Unstable reading from Raspberry Pi

Tags: arduino-mega

I'm trying to send a signal from Raspberry Pi GPIO to Arduino. I made a sketch that basically reads the state of the digital read, but the reading are very unstable. I understand that there is a floated voltage and the obvious solution is to configure the pullup resistor and connect the input to ground, but my goal is to read the incoming signal.
I'm using Arduino Mega 2560 and Raspberry Pi 2B.

I hope this info is enough!

Comment: Please show your schematic.

Comment: It is just GPIO 5 conected to A3 of Arduino Mega.

Comment: If GPIO5 is the only thing connected and the Arduino/Rpi are on seperate power supplies then you are certainly missing a common ground reference if you want them to talk directly.

Comment: Thank you guys for your answers! Now,  what should I do?

Comment: Connect the grounds together.

Comment: Thank you! I know this was a silly question, buy I really apreciate your help! Have a nice day!

Comment: Did that comment resolve your problem? If it did it would be nice to create an answer so that others will see this as a resolved question.

Comment: You might want to check the details on the answer of Majenko (https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/02/01/making-accurate-adc-readings-on-the-arduino/#more-12)

Answer (score 2):

As Majenko commented, you need to not only connect the data wires together but also the ground wire (from the Arduino to the Pi).

> ... the reading are very unstable ...

Without a consistent "ground reference" the readings would indeed be unstable.

Comment: Occasionally you run into situations where connecting grounds causes problems in which case a dual supply buffer or isolator can be used

Comment: @crasic that's a very interesting point (maybe not in this case, but) you might want to elaborate it in your own answer or by editing Nick's answer. In what cases should it be used, why and how?